# I am using Rails 5, I created a custom page loader using css. What I want to do is to first display this page loader before loading any page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, css

How can I achieve this? What would be my Jquery code for this and where shall I place it?

here's my page loader css

```
body {
background: #000000;
text-align: center;
padding: 20%;
letter-spacing: 7px;
}

.loading span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: .19em;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /*transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);*/
  animation: loading 1.3s infinite;

  }

  .loading span:nth-of-type(1){
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
   animation-delay: 0.1s;
   }


.loading span:nth-of-type(3) {
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
  background:   #ffffff;
 animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
```

and here's my login html page but before displaying this page or any other page i want to display my loader first.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html >
   <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login page</title>

   </head>

    <body>
   <div class="loading">
    <span></span>     
      <span></span>
         <span></span>
          </div>
        <div class="login-form">
       <%= form_for(:user) do |f|%>
     <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Username" %>
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group pass">
           <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Password" %>
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
       </div>

       <%= f.label :remember_me, class: "checkbox" do %>
       <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
       <span>Remember me</span>
       <% end %>


      <button class="log-btn btn btn-primary"  >Sign In</button>
      <% end %>



     <a href="https://rails-muneebzak6502.c9users.io/profile/help" class="link-1">
      Forgot Password?</a>


     </div>


      </body>

      </html>
```

How can I first display the loader and then the page user called for? What Jquery should I use and where should I use it, so it's included throughout the app.

Comment: Do you want to display the spinner before the page gets displayed or after the user presses the sign-in button?

Comment: every time the user requests a page, my custom loader should appear first and then the page. @Wukerplank

Comment: This is not how the usual request/response cycle works with Rails. I think you are going to have to jump through a lot of hoops to get this behaviour. Voting to close this question for being to broad.